# Apache Spark, creating hive context - NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, exception, apache-spark, hive

I have a following problem, my main method is:

```
static public void main(String args[]){
     SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestHive");
     SparkContext sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf);
     HiveContext hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);    
}
```

And I build it with `mvn package`
Then I submit my code, however I get following exception. I have no idea what's wrong:

```
sh spark-submit --class "TestHive" --master local[4] ~/target/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getTimeVar(org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
```

Tell me please, where I am wrong.

PS I built my spark with hive and thriftServer.

```
Spark 1.5.2 built for Hadoop 2.4.0
Build flags: -Psparkr -Phadoop-2.4 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pyarn
```

Comment: when you are doing `mvn package` do you have a "fat jar"? which means a jar that contains all the dependencies??

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, using exactly the same code as yours. I think it might be the version of spark-hive, would you please list the maven dependency `<artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>` ? which version are you using?

Comment: Yes, you are right, It was about hive version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be version conflict between spark components (spark-core, spark-sql and spark-hive)

To avoid this conflit all versions of those components should be the same.  You could do that in your `pom.xml` by setting a peroperty called spark.version for example:

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>1.6.0</spark.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```