# Getting Error when I ran hive UDF written in Java in pyspark EMR 5.x

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, hive-udf

I have a Hive UDF written in java and I am trying to use it in pyspark 2.0.0. below are the steps
1. Copy the jar file to EMR
2. started a pyspark job like below

```
pyspark --jars ip-udf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-latest.jar
```

3. used the below code access the UDF

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("create temporary function ip_map as 'com.mediaiq.hive.IPMappingUDF'")
```

I get the below error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.sql.
>   : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getTimeVar(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf$ConfVars;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:189)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I looked into the below link but not of much help.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491483/how-to-call-a-hive-udf-written-in-java-using-pyspark-from-hive-context]

Answer (score 0):

You may have built your UDF with a different version of Hive. Be sure to specify the same version of Hive in your `pom.xml` used to build the jar containing the UDF. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920579/apache-spark-creating-hive-context-nosuchmethodexception), for example.